# Using Scala to Write a DF to a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use the code below.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

// Aquire a DataFrame collection (val collection)

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"          -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName" -> "MyDatabase",
  "dbTable"      -> "dbo.Clients"
  "user"         -> "username",
  "password"     -> "*********"
))

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
collection.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).sqlDB(config)
```

The script is from this link.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark

I'm running this in a databricks environment.  I'm getting these errors:

```
command-836397363127942:5: error: object sqlDB is not a member of package com.microsoft.azure
import com.microsoft.azure.sqlDB.spark.connect._
                           ^
command-836397363127942:4: error: object sqlDB is not a member of package com.microsoft.azure
import com.microsoft.azure.sqlDB.spark.config.Config
                           ^
command-836397363127942:7: error: not found: value Config
val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
                     ^
command-836397363127942:18: error: value sqlDB is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).sqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

I'm guessing that some kind of library is not installed correctly.  I Googled for an answer, but didn't find anything useful.  Any idea how to make this work?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you included the connector dependency `azure-sqldb-spark` ? It seems it's missing

Comment: add this and try  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-sqldb-spark -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-sqldb-spark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the `sqldb` error means all other support libraries already imported to your notebook and only the latest JAR with dependencies are missing.

As per the repro, I got the same error message as shown above:

[image]

After bit of research, I had found that you will experience this error due to missing JAR with dependencies.

To resolve this issue, you need to download the JAR file from here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-sqldb-spark/1.0.2/jar

[image]

After downloaded the jar file, upload the JAR library into the cluster and install it.

**Note:** After installing both the libraries, make sure to `restart` the cluster.

[image]

Now, you will be able to run the command successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I think you have missed the library**

1. If your using **Maven Build** Add the following library in pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure-sqldb-spark</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. If your using **SBT Build** Add the following library in build.sbt

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-sqldb-spark" % "1.0.2"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported and installed the library in DataBricks?

I found it easiest to import the library using Maven. See this answer: [How to install a library on a databricks cluster using some command in the notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543850/how-to-install-a-library-on-a-databricks-cluster-using-some-command-in-the-noteb)

Note: You need to install the Library on your cluster and then restart the cluster before you can use it.