# How to install a library on a databricks cluster using some command in the notebook?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Actually I want to install a library on my Azure databricks cluster but I cannot use the UI method because every time my cluster would change and in transition I cannot add library to it using UI. Is there any databricks utility command for doing this?

Comment: have you tried databricks [libraries CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/libraries-cli.html) then install the library from DBFS.

Answer (score 0):

@CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT's answer is awesome! Just a complement:

If you want all your notebooks / clusters to have the same libs installed, you can take advantage of cluster-scoped or global (new feature) init scripts.

The example below retrieves packages from PyPi:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Install dependencies
pip install --upgrade boto3 psycopg2-binary requests simple-salesforce
```

You can even use a private package index - for example AWS CodeArtifact:

```
#Install AWS CLI
pip install --upgrade awscli

# Configure pip
aws codeartifact login --region <REGION> --tool pip --domain <DOMAIN> --domain-owner <AWS_ACCOUNT_ID> --repository <REPO>
pip config set global.extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple
```

*Note: the cluster instance profile must be allowed to get CodeArtifact credentials (`arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeArtifactReadOnlyAccess`).*

Cheers

Comment: Follow up question. How do you configure the instance to get the AWS credentials?

Comment: @pmanDS We currently attach an "Instance profile" in the Advanced options of the cluster configuration page.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP's answer?  I don't see that here? I you referring to some other post or perhaps it was delete?

Comment: that answer was removed by StackOverflow moderator and couldn't be restored until another moderator will chime in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *%pip install* command to install the required libraries from within your notebook code. This documentation provides further detail on its usage: https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html. For example:

```
!pip install requests
```

For older runtimes there was dbutils.library utility (https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-library) but it was deprecated.