# Installing Maven library on Databricks via Python commands and dbutils

Tags: python, maven, databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

On Databricks I would like to install a Maven library through commands in a Python Notebook if its not already installed.

If it were a Python PyPI library I would do something like the following:

```
# Get a list of all available library 
library_name_list = dbutils.library.list()
# Suppose the library of interest was "scikit-learn"
if "scikit-learn" not in library_name_list:
  # Install the library 
  dbutils.library.installPyPI("scikit-learn")
```

How can I do the same for a Maven library "com.microsoft.azure.kusto:spark-kusto-connector:2.0.0" i.e. check if it is already installed, if not then install?

I can install the Maven library using the UI by going to "Clusters" -> "Libraries" -> "Install New" -> "Maven". But I would like to do it programmatically through a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** Library utilities (`dbutils.library.installPyPI("")`) allow you to install **Python libraries** and create an environment scoped to a notebook session.

**Here are the steps to programmatically way to install libraries from the maven repository:**

> You can use Databricks CLI to install maven libraries in Azure Databricks.

**Step1:** From maven coordinates, you can go to Maven Repository and pick the version which you are looking for and note the dependency (groupId, artifactId, and Version).

[image]

**Step2** Get the cluster-ID using databricks CLI.

To get the cluster-ID: `databricks clusters list`

[image]

**Step3:** Use the below Databricks CLI command to install  '`com.microsoft.azure.kusto:spark-kusto-connector:2.0.0`' in Databricks.

**Syntax:** `databricks libraries install --cluster-id "Cluster ID" --maven-coordinates "GroupId:ArtifactId:Version" (i.e.org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2)`

To install the maven library using databricks CLI: `databricks libraries install --cluster-id "1013-095611-mazes551" --maven-coordinates "com.microsoft.azure.kusto:spark-kusto-connector:2.0.0"`

To check the install libraries on the cluster: `databricks libraries list --cluster-id "1013-095611-mazes551"`

[image]

For different methods to install packages in Azure Databricks, refer: [How to install a library on a databricks cluster using some command in the notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543850/how-to-install-a-library-on-a-databricks-cluster-using-some-command-in-the-noteb/60557852#60557852)