# How could I resolve ImportError: no module named 'azureml', I am using Azure databricks notebook

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to creating similar machine learning experiment as on found on github at below link.

https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-orange-juice-sales/auto-ml-forecasting-orange-juice-sales.ipynb

what could I do to resolve the ImportEror:?

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To resolve this issue, I would request you to install azureml library from PyPi packages.

To make third-party or locally-built code available to notebooks and jobs running on your clusters, you can install a library. Libraries can be written in Python, Java, Scala, and R. You can upload Java, Scala, and Python libraries and point to external packages in PyPI, Maven, and CRAN repositories.

**Steps to install third-party libraries:**

**Step1:** Create Databricks Cluster.

**Step2:** Select the cluster created.

**Step3:** Select Libraries => Install New => Select Library Source = "PYPI" => Package = "azureml-sdk[databricks]".

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [Set up a development environment with Azure Databricks and autoML in Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-databricks-automl-environment)

For different methods to install packages in Azure Databricks: [How to install a library on a databricks cluster using some command in the notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543850/how-to-install-a-library-on-a-databricks-cluster-using-some-command-in-the-noteb/60557852#60557852)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.