# Installing Janitor library in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I have Python 3.7 installed.
Trying to install `janitor` library in `Azure DataBricks`. It works properly in my local machine, but have difficulty to be installed in `Azure DataBricks`.

I run `dbutils.library.installPyPI('janitor')`, but got the below error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`. I tried `butils.library.installPyPI('mysqlclient')`, as mentioned in 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser', but didn't work.

Comment: Did you install `ConfigParser` ?

Comment: I did `Requirement already satisfied: ConfigParser in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.0.2)`, but it gives me the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` when I run `import janitor`

Answer (score 0):

`dbutils.library.installPyPI` is a deprecated method ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#library-utility-dbutilslibrary)). You need to use `%pip install janitor` instead (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html))

Comment: I did `%sh pip install janitor`, but still shows error. I also run `%pip install janitor`, but it gave me `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Conda and pip magic commands are currently not supported in Databricks. To modify the environment on driver only, you can use %sh. `

Comment: What DBR version?

Comment: DBR 6.4, Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11

Answer (score 0):

> You can install Janitor library using `%pip install janitor`.

[image]

Based on your Databricks Runtime, if you are unable to install using the above command you can use any alternative method to install library: [different methods to install packages in Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543850/how-to-install-a-library-on-a-databricks-cluster-using-some-command-in-the-noteb/60557852#60557852).

Comment: It gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`, however I run `%sh pip install ConfigParser`. It seems `ConfigParser` has been installed as `Collecting ConfigParser
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/01/ff260a18caaf4457eb028c96eeb405c4a230ca06c8ec9c1379f813caa52e/configparser-5.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: ConfigParser
Successfully installed ConfigParser-5.0.2
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`, but NO.
I'm still getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`

Comment: @AmnKh Could you please share the Databricks Runtime which you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The python implementation of this great library is pyjanitor:

```
pip install pyjanitor
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyjanitor/