# PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto''

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, pyspark

I'm getting errors while decrypting, the encrypted column in pyspark, here is mycode. BTW, I'm writing below code in Azure databricks.

```
%sh
/databricks/python3/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install pycryptodome
python3 -m pip install padding
```

```
%python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
import sys
import binascii
import Padding
from binascii import unhexlify
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


def encrypt(plaintext,key, mode,iv):
    encobj = AES.new(key,mode,iv) 
    return(binascii.hexlify(bytearray(encobj.encrypt(plaintext))).decode())


def decrypt(ciphertext):
  password='xxx'
  ival='xxxxxx'
  key = hashlib.md5(password.encode()).digest()
  iv = bytearray(ival.encode())
  encobj = AES.new(key,mode,iv)
  return(encobj.decrypt(unhexlify(ciphertext)))


udf_func = udf(decrypt ,StringType())

df = df.withColumn("decrypt_column",udf_func(col('Response')))
```

Here is the error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4915.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4915.0 (TID 32555) (172.30.8.16 executor 2): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto''. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto''. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

From the error, I decipher that, I will need to install packages on worker nodes too, How do I do that?  thanks for the help.

Comment: See if this helps -> https://medium.com/@rajparmar23801/no-module-named-crypto-707f75186a6a

Answer (score 4):

First we can understand on magic command `%sh`. If you install any packages through `%sh` magic command ,  packages will not be available in all workers node. This will be available only in driver node. If we understand this , we can understand on this issue . You can check the [link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#summary-table-and-diagram) for complete understanding.

For your question , We can install library in cluster level in multiple ways like `cluster UI, Libraries API,Libraries CLI, Library utilities`. You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543850/how-to-install-a-library-on-a-databricks-cluster-using-some-command-in-the-noteb).